# Taking a snapshot of state asynchronosly

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, scheduling

I have the following scenario:

- Thread 1 does some computation
- Thread 2 may want to take a snapshot of the latest result in thread 1
- Thread 2 does not have any insight in what is happening in thread 1. Thus, a ping-pong buffer may not be possible here.

I tried the following implementation:

- Thread 1 will call the computation function repeatedly, while holding a mutex:

```cpp
void do_run()
{
    while(!m_should_stop.load())
    {
        std::lock_guard lock{m_task_mtx};
        if(m_task.step() == task_step_result::task_is_completed)
        { return; } 
    }
}
```

- Thread 2 will try to acquire the mutex so it can safely fetch the state

```cpp
state get_state() const
{
    std::lock_guard lock{m_task_mtx};
    return m_task.current_state();
}
```

The problem is that `get_state` never gets a chance to acquire the mutex, unless there is an artificial sleep before the lock is captured by `do_run`. Could this problem be solved in some other way, such as using some priority schema. If `get_state` is waiting on the resource, it should have priority over `step`.

Comment: A mutex only needs to be held when ***synchronizing access to the same object in different threads***. There is no requirement, whatsoever, to hold a mutex by an execution thread when it "does some computation". Nothing in that mysterious `step()` should be updating any shared object. Acquire a mutex only after `step()` returns, update the shared state, release the mutex. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Why is thread 1 busy-looping?

Comment: here's a solution with two mutexes: thread 1: while(!stop){lock 1; unlock 1; lock 2; do stuff; unlock 2;} thread 2: lock 1; lock 2; get state; unlock 1/2 (order doesn't matter)

Comment: @user253751 How does that work?

Comment: @PaulSanders The idea is to make room for other threads to access the resource. step in it self may execute a number of iterations, then it should yield so the management thread can access the resources if desired.

Comment: @PaulSanders But see the constraint that it is not possible with double-buffering due to architectural constraints.

Comment: @user877329 Thread 2 uses the extra mutex to force thread 1 to wait so thread 2 can get the real mutex. I'm sure there are also other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by injecting the request into thread 1. Basically it becomes like this

### Thread 1:

1. Check the mailbox, if not empty

   1. Execute the task
   2. Clear the mailbox
   3. Notify Thread 2 that the result is ready (via a `condition_variable`)
2. Continue with the real work

### Thread 2:

1. Store data about what Thread 1 should execute (a function pointer, a pointer to the closure, and a pointer to the storage for the return value). The return value is stored inside std::optional
2. Use the condition_variable and wait for the data to become available

### The commuincation channel:

```cpp
class sync_message_bus
{
public:
    void operator()()  // Called from Thread 1
    {
        std::lock_guard lock{m_mtx};
        if(m_closure != nullptr) [[unlikely]]
        {
            m_callback(m_closure, m_result);
            m_closure = nullptr;
            m_cv.notify_one();
        }
    }
    template<class Callable>
    auto process(Callable&& f, bool invoke_now)  // Called from Thread 2
    {
        if(invoke_now)  // In case Thread 1 is not running
        { return std::forward<Callable>(f)(); }
        using type = std::invoke_result_t<Callable>;
        std::optional<type> retval;
        {
            std::unique_lock lock{m_mtx};
            m_closure = &f;
            m_callback = [](void* closure, void* result) {
                auto& f = *static_cast<Callable*>(closure);
                auto& retval = *static_cast<std::optional<type>*>(result);
                retval = f();
            };
            m_result = &retval;
            m_cv.wait(lock, [&retval](){
                return retval.has_value();
            });
        }
        return std::move(*retval);
    }

private:
    std::mutex m_mtx;
    void* m_closure{nullptr};
    void (*m_callback)(void* value, void* result){nullptr};
    void* m_result{nullptr};
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
};
```